Odd and Unintended Formatting
I just recently answered the following question: MM strategy to interactive with IB API. 
See my answer here. 
However in my answer, spaces were deleted, lines spaced oddly and italics added to portions of the text. I extensively reviewed my answer and cannot find anything at all to point to this problem. 
Any insight and / or edit suggestions would be greatly appreciated! 

The dollar signs trigger LATEX formatting, this has now been fixed.

The dollar signs triggers $\LaTeX$ formatting, this has now been fixed.
You can fix this by escaping the $ by \.
